# Import and export of PGN

Tags: engines, pgn

How do I perform the following related things?

- Export/import PGN of games from Droidfish.
- Import my games to Chess.com

I found an option to export my games from Chess.com (**Share PGN**) but I couldn't find any options for the rest of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the link for [chess.com import pgn (as text)](https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor)

You should do the following:

Copy the content of the PGN file into clipboard

1. Open your PGN file in your favorite editor (e.g. notepad)
2. Mark the content of the PGN
3. Copy the PGN content into the clipboard (e.g. using <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>)
4. Open [chess.com import pgn](https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor)

[image: chess.com import page]

5. Choose Load PGN
6. Paste the PGN content from clipboard (e.g. using <kbd>CTRL + V</kbd>)
7. Choose Load

Comment: Thank you for the answer(+1)! How about importing /exporting games to /from Droidfish?

Answer (score 5):

### Importing and exporting games to and from Droidfish

Hold down on the board, and a set of options appear:
[image: Screen for import/export of games]

- Click on **Share Game** or **Clipboard** to share (export) PGN.
- Click on **Retrieve Position** to import PGN from your device. Alternatively, if you have the game on Clipboard, you can click **Clipboard** and then choose to paste the game from Clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Another method for exporting games from DroidFish is:

- Enter the game on a new board
- Long press the "M", then choose "File", then "Save game to PGN file". Create a new file if you don't have one already
- This file can be found on your device's storage under `/DroidFish/pgn`.  I accessed it with AirDroid but you could use any file manager app or even USB connection.

This will work for multiple games in one file.